# Python internal variables - where to find a list of all?

Tags: python, environment-variables

Which other variables exist internally in Python, beyond `__doc__` and `__annotations__`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Data Model Docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#specialnames) and [Built-in Functions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) will have a list and description of what you are looking for.